# Group objects into fixed-sized collections

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to take a collection of entries in a zip file and group related ones together. I know there should be 4 entries to a group. I tried the following:

```
var entryGroups = zipArchive.Entries
            .OrderBy(entry => entry.FullName)
            .Select((entry, index) => new {index, entry})
            .GroupBy(entry => entry.index % groupSize)
            .Select(group => group.Select(grouping => grouping.entry));
```

Unfortunately, that gives me 4 large groups, whereas I am looking for many groups which have 4 entries each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be worth trying with `/` rather than `%`

```
var entryGroups = zipArchive.Entries
        .OrderBy(entry => entry.FullName)
        .Select((entry, index) => new {index, entry})
        .GroupBy(entry => entry.index / groupSize)
        .Select(group => group.Select(grouping => grouping.entry));
```

Comment: Sigh... this is what happens when the coffee maker breaks down!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the remainder operator `%` with integer division `/`

Use the reminder operator with create only `n` groups, Not groups of size `n`.  Use integer division (`/`) for dividing into `n` groups.  Note that the final group might be a few elements short (it will be the remainder).